# How to send data from OLE DB source to Anchor model tables using ETL procedure?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, business-intelligence, anchor-modeling

I'm currently solving this task: some data should be sent from AdventureWorks2012 to Anchor model tables on the same server in MsSQL. 
This is my Anchor Model 
[image: Anchor model]

[image: Anchor Model diagram in MsSQL]

At this point I have a pretty simple Integration Services project in Visual Studio and it looks like this.
Control flow:
[image]
For example Load_territories is:
[image: ![enter image description here]

The main requirement is to fill all tables of Anchor model tables in MsSQL but I'm constantly facing a problem: the amount of attributes in tables are different and some of them are repeating
At this picture in the second table basically TR_ID,TR_GRP_TR_ID, TR_TID_TR_ID, TR_TNM_TR_ID contain the same values from dwh_key but it's impossible to create a one-to-many relation between attributes. My tutor has recommended me to use Lookup but I cannot figure out how to implement them in this project
[image]

Comment: consider to accept an answer or provide the feedback why it didn't address your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be considered as cheating, but if you insert data into the latest view rather than the separate 6NF tables all of those ID fields will be populated by underlying trigger logic. I suspect that this would defeat the purpose of using SSIS though, since you would effectively be loading attributes sequentially rather than in parallel.

Another option is to leave surrogate key management to the ETL tool. This would require that you switch the data type for your identities from integers to GUID:s. SSIS can then generate a GUID and you can then use that very same GUID to populate all the attributes. Note that the anchor would have to be loaded first, or you will get a foreign key violation.

The most common solution though, is to leave surrogate key management to the database (and use integers). You would have a step in which you populate the metadata column in the anchor with the desired number of new identities to be created. Using the metadata number you can then select the newly generated identities and merge them into your data flow. It doesn't matter which number gets assigned to which row. After that all attributes can be populated in parallel, including their ID columns.

Of course, if this is intended to be used for more than an initial load, you would also have to add steps to detect if the data you are loading is already known or not.

I can also recommend watching the video tutorial referenced in this blog post: https://clinthuijbers.wordpress.com/2013/06/14/ssis-anchor-modeling-example-tutorial/